# Best way to install python packages locally for development

Tags: python, installation

Being new to the python games I seem to have missed out on some knowledge on how you can develop on a program but also keep it in your live environment.

Programs like gpodder can be run directly from the source checkout which is really handy  however others want to be "installed" to run.

A lot of programs are distributed with a setup.py with instructions to run "python ./setup.py install" as root which will put stuff somewhere in your file-system. There are even install commands like "develop" which seem to hold the promise of what I want. So I tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/alex/python
python ./setup.py develop --install-dir=/home/alex/python
```

Which downloaded a bunch of stuff locally and seems magically ensure the application I'm hacking on is still being run out of the src tree. So I guess my roundabout question is is this the correct way of developing python code? How do things like easy_install and pip factor into this?

So I tried the following:

```
 python /usr/share/pyshared/virtualenv.py /home/alex/src/goobook
 cd /home/alex/src/goobook/googbook.git
 /home/alex/src/goobook/bin/python ./setup.py develop
```

And finally linked the program in question to my ~/bin

```
 cd /home/alex/src/goobook
 linkbin.pl bin/goobook
```

However invocation throws up a load of extra chatter which seems to imply it's wrong:

```
17:17 alex@socrates/i686 [goobook] >goobook --help
/home/alex/bin/goobook:5: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from        /home/alex/src/goobook/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c8-py2.5.egg/pkg_resources.py, but /home/alex/src/goobook/lib/python2.5/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.5.egg is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
/home/alex/bin/goobook:5: UserWarning: Module site was already imported from /home/alex/src/goobook/lib/python2.5/site.pyc, but /home/alex/src/goobook/lib/python2.5/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.5.egg is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
```

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors.  Most likely things will work fine.  It's interesting that you have both setuptools *and* distribute installed inside your virtualenv (this is what causes the warning); distribute is a replacement for setuptools.

Comment: Ahh, this may be a feature of the package if playing with. It seems to download distribute as part of the setup. Should it only being doing one or the other?

http://gitorious.org/goobook/mainline/blobs/master/setup.py

Comment: It seems the problem has gone away with the update to Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

to set up a localized virtual environment for your libraries, and:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

i.e. "easy_install" to install new things.

Comment: It almost worked, see the question for the problems I ran into.

Comment: @stsquad: i think it matters what python you use when setting up the virtualenv and then when using the virtualenv-installed things. it appears above what you may have used 2 different versions. also, set up your `PYTHONPATH` to point to the new stuff and not the old stuff, and reload your shell. i'm guessing that it might be conflicting with the previous installation...

Comment: virtualenv installs setuptools (or distribute, which is a newer replacement for it) inside the virtualenv; you don't need to install setuptools explicitly as a second step.  If you did, that may be what causes those UserWarnings you see.

Comment: Updating for 2014: `distribute` is now a deprecated/obsolete fork, and `setuptools` is the new `setuptools` again. It still comes with `virtualenv` automatically—as does `pip`, which is what you should use, not `easy_install`. Meanwhile, Python 3.3 comes with `venv`, a `virtualenv`-like solution, and in Python 3.4, `venv` automatically installs `pip`. So, there's nothing to do but [read the `venv`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html) docs.

Answer (score 5):

[Virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) allows you to work in completely independent and isolated Python environments. It will let you easily create multiple environments which have different Python packages installed or different versions of a same package. Virtualenv also lets you easily switch between your different environments.

As of 2012, the de facto preferred tool for package management in Python is [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) rather than setuptools. Pip is able to handle dependencies and to install/uninstall globally or inside a virtual environment. Pip even comes out-of-the-box with virtualenv.

#### Python 3

Also worth mentioning is the fact that virtual environments are becoming a part of Python itself in [release 3.3](http://blog.python.org/2012/08/python-33-beta-2-released.html), with the implementation of [PEP 405](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/).

Answer (score 4):

The [Python Packaging User Guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/), which "aims to be the authoritative resource on how to package, publish and install Python distributions using current tools", recommends using pip to install in "development mode":

```
pip install -e <path>
```

Thus in the root directory of your package you can simply

```
pip install -e .
```

See [installing from a local source tree](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/installing/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree).

Comment: @stsquad This approach will use the `setup.py` file located in `<path>` behind the scenes to set up the package.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to develop Python apps with dependencies is to:

1. Download desired version of the python interpreter.
2. Install and use buildout (http://www.buildout.org/).

Buildout is something like Maven for Java (will fetch all needed packages automatically).

This way your Python interpreter will not be polluted by third party packages (this is important if you will be running developed application on other machines). Additionally you can integrate buildout with virtualenv package (this allows you to create virtual python interpreters for each project).