# What python virtual environment and deployment solution should I use?

Tags: python, virtualenv, buildout

I'm looking for a virtual environment solution for Python applications and I would like something that respects these requirements:

- Windows and Linux
- works with x86/x64 Python versions
- easy to use/maintain
- Python 2.6-2.7 compatible and preferably even 3.x
- source control friendly - I want to keep the packages in SCM.

So far I identified [virtual-python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout), but at least buildout does not supports py3. I'm not looking for a list of solutions, only one you recommend, preferably after you used more than one.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281495/best-way-to-install-python-packages-locally-for-development/3281590#3281590

Comment: This question is very different than the one above, it not limited to dev-environment and also has some specific requirements. Still they are related.

Comment: virtual-python and virtualenv are two different things; your link names one but goes to the other.  virtualenv is newer and better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either virtualenv or zc.buildout will work.  Virtualenv is easier to learn and use; buildout is more powerful.  I personally use buildout for development/deployment of packages I develop, and virtualenv for deployment of 3rd-party applications (like Trac).

Disclaimer: I've never attempted to use either on Windows, or on Python 3.  I see that there's a version of virtualenv that works in Python 3, and there's a branch of zc.buildout that attempts to add Python 3 support (but it seems to be abandoned).